# How to set up docker with a node.js application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, google-app-engine, containers

I am trying to run pupeteer on Google App Engine and I need to have the app in a docker container in order to have chrome available. My question is how do you set up docker with a node.js application?

Comment: You can follow the next tutorial https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/nodejs-docker-webapp/

Comment: @AlexandruOlaru, I think you can share your mesage as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a DockerFile with the version of NodeJS you want using FROM instruction.

At the top of your DockerFile :

> FROM node:x.xx.x

Or you can simply pull an image from Docker, try to find what you need at : [Docker store](http://store.docker.com)

Maybe this one could help you :

> docker pull node